# How to import mongdb exported data

Tags: mongodb, import

I have some data exported from mongodb. Now, I'm trying to import it into another database: 
    import --db local --collection CollectionTest1 --type json --file mytest.json
I kept receiving the error:
    Failed: Error processing document #2 invalid character ',' looking for     beginning of value
So, I ran it through jslint and sure enough, it isn't valid json, because it has mongo types in it like ISODate(...). Looking through the help file, I don't see anyway to handle this. Surely, it can import its own exports, right? 
Any idea how to import such a file:
{
    "_id" : "AGE",
    "CreatedAt" : ISODate("2016-06-14T18:15:32.600Z"),
    "CreatedBy" : "Guest User",
    "UpdatedAt" : ISODate("2016-06-14T18:15:32.600Z"),
    "UpdatedBy" : "Guest User",
    "Controlled" : false,
    "DraftSuffix" : "",
    ...

Comment: What is your MongoDB version? Also, how did you export your data? Am I right in thinking that by `import` you mean `mongoimport`?

Comment: Yes, I meant mongoimport.  I'm running 3.2.9, I'm not certain what version it was exported from.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong unless we can see the actual data, but if you exported the data using `mongoexport`, then it will export one JSON document per MongoDB document, which will fail validation since there's multiple JSON documents in one file (although `mongoimport` will read it just fine). Could you share the command line you used to export the collection?

Comment: I'll try to get the exact command(s) used. A colleague did it for me.

Comment: The files originally came in a a .tar.gz file.